# how to replace sublist in LogoList

Tags: java, netlogo

I have a logolist like:

```
[[(turtle 0) 91.21412595730608] [(turtle 1) 76.89996795823208] [(turtle 2) 72.61621123351073] [(turtle 3) 71.23366936658486] [(turtle 5) 69.5448418866364]]
```

I need to replace one of the sublist with a new LogoList, say I have to replace:

```
[(turtle 0) 91.21412595730608]
```

with:

```
[(turtle 0) 43.4323424]
```

I am attempting to make the change with this code:

```
private LogoList replaceItem(LogoList euclideanDistance, LogoListBuilder innerEuclDist, Turtle s) {
    ListIterator<Object> listIterator = euclideanDistance.listIterator();
    int idx = 0;
    while (listIterator.hasNext()) {
        LogoList next = (LogoList) listIterator.next();
        Turtle get = (Turtle) next.get(0);
        if (get.equals(s)) {
            return euclideanDistance.replaceItem(idx, innerEuclDist.toLogoList());
        }
        idx += 1;
    }
    return null;
}
```

but I am wondering if there is some more clever / fast solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me. I don't see any room for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a remove and an add or use ReplaceAll as per http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-

Comment: You can have a list of only one element. Go after code readability.  Performance will follow.